# php artisan migrate: [PDOException]could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have searched all over the Internet (including Stack Overflow) for an answer regarding this recent problem I've encountered.

I'm trying to install and run the latest version of the Laravel PHP Framework and am currently going through the QuickStart steps.  When I get to the Migration steps after creating the view files and a 'user' table, I keep getting thrown with the 'PDOEXCEPTION' error -> 'could not find driver'.

Here are the steps I have taken so far in attempting to install Laravel.

System Specs -> Windows 7 PC with WAMP server installed and PHP5 installed as a separate folder.

**Steps:**

1. Installed 'Composer' Tool for PHP.  After downloading the install file and running setup, it found the 'PHP' directory on my hard drive located on (C:\PHP) and continued to install via that PATH.
2. Installed 'Laravel' by using 'Composer' by typing in the following command into my command terminal via the 'PHP' directory (C:\PHP) -> 'composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist'
3. Went into my new 'blog' project (C:\php\blog) and modified the files 'C:\php\blog\app\routes.php', 'C:\php\blog\app\views\users.blade.php', 'C:\php\blog\app\views\layout.blade.php'.
4. Used the following command to create a migration within the 'blog' project (C:\php\blog) 'php artisan migrate:make create_users_table'.  After creating this file, I modified it according to the Laravel online Quickstart Guide.
5. After I modified this program, I then typed in 'php artisan migrate' and that's when I keep getting the PDOEXCEPTION: 'could not find driver' problem.

I have checked my php.ini file and the extension for the php_pdo_mysql.dll is set and I still keep getting this error.

After spending a lot of time researching this error, I still cannot figure out what is causing this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please help me guys!

Comment: Did not fully understood, you have separate PHP installation and WAMP running at the same time?

Comment: I have 2 folders installed, 1 folder (C:\WAMP) that contains all the WAMP server files etc.  The other (C:\PHP) which contains all the PHP files.

Comment: Just use Laravel Homestead. Trying to run in native windows always ends up with issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took The Shift Exchange's advice and downloaded Laravel Homestead and I now have my system up and running.

Use the following link for steps in installing Laravel Homestead properly: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Note that if you are using Windows, you'll probably have to use Putty to connect to your VirtualBox machine properly.